# What's the simplest set-up to demonstrate soiless plant growth to middle school students?

Tags: plant-physiology

I'm looking for a simple, inexpensive way to demonstrate that soil is not needed for plant growth to middle school students.  I plan to germinate bean seeds in cotton, but where do I take it from there?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a glass mason jar, a bean seed, and a moist paper towel. Place the seed between the paper towel and the glass. If you press the paper towel so that it lines the inside of the glass jar, the seed with grow and the students can see this process through the glass.